# Showcase good questions or answers

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, profile-page

This is related to [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/let-me-link-best-of-answers-to-my-resume-profile) which is nice to have on the Careers profile. However, it would be nice to have on any Stack Exchange profile as well.

I'm thinking of a better way to promote the questions/answers you're most proud of, or that you think are really good. A lot of these questions get maybe 1-2 votes and an accept, and that's it.

Currently questions/answers on the profile can be sorted by `votes | activity | newest`. Maybe add a new category there -  `showcase` , where you can manually add 5-10 questions/answers you really like.

If you look at my Stack Overflow profile, the top answer is a very simple one to a very simple question. I'm not particularly fond of that answer, and I would like to showcase other answers where I put more work in.

Note that GitHub suffered from the same problem where there was a lot of noise in people's profiles, and they implemented *Pinned Repositories*, a great feature in my opinion.

Comment: And that's why you don't go around answering off topic or joke questions

Comment: @random I'm not talking about off topic etc. There is a certain pattern where the questions in high traffic categories get a lot of attention...or the simple questions that most people understand

Comment: You'd have to teach people to upvote more than one-liners and read beyond questions/answers that are plainly explained in the manual/docs.

Comment: Create a blog. Put up your top 10 answers. Use your bio to link to your blog. Feature implemented.

Comment: When you say "the usual bashing", are you referring to the fact that people have downvoted your feature request? In fact, that's expected and encouraged behavior on Meta. People who disagree with feature requests downvote them. People who agree, upvote them. This is covered in the [FAQ].

Answer (score 5):

I [proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253687/162102) something like this on a call for proposals for "micro-privileges".  I still think it's a good idea, because sometimes your best work is obscure and thus not highly-voted.

> Give users a place on the profile (Profile rather than Activity; this is outward-facing) to collect, say, up to 10 posts that they're most proud of or otherwise want to show off. Sometimes your best work isn't high-scoring (maybe it's in an obscure, low-traffic tag), or maybe you just think everything clicked on that post and you want to show it off a little. [...]
>
> This idea was inspired by the part of the Careers profile where you can advertise selected answers from across the network. (And I imagine reusing some code from there.) My proposal includes questions and not just answers, because a well-asked question can be a thing of beauty too. And my proposal is tied to a particular site, both selection and viewing; I see this being about "my best work *here*", not "my best work in a job hunt" or "my best work for all viewers in all contexts".

Here's a mockup of how this would fit into the profile page, with the change highlighted (sorry for lack of red freehand circle):

[image: Mockup]

See the linked answer for more about how it could be implemented.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for back then, and still do 6 years later. I just made a small edit pointing out the Pinned Repositories on Github, which show that this suggestion is not complete nonsense despite the negativity here.

Comment: I don't know why people are being so negative either. Since you asked this question the profile page was split into "profile" (mainly for the public, includes your "about" block, etc) and "activity" (mainly for you). With that philosophy, allowing curation of the posts shown there seems logical to me; if you want to see things strictly by score you can get that from "activity" or the other tabs here. Sure, people can edit all this into the "about" block, but that's a lot of work compared to just checking off posts to include automatically. Much of the work was already done for Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Both good questions and answers are showcased [through the badge system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/175248).  I don't see any necessity to show it off any further, since if someone's really curious, they could always look at that badge, and see what question/answer merited the badge.

Comment: yes but this is still determined by the number of votes...so we end up in the same loop: more traffic <-> more votes

Comment: @mihai, I'm not quite sure what you mean.  The number of votes *should* determine what the community thinks is a good question or answer.

Comment: yes, you are right...the community...not me

Comment: @Makoto the point of the request is to allow users to say "hey, this answer of mine on an obscure tag that most voters don't know enough to be able to evaluate is good stuff and I want to make it more visible".  That visibility might, for example, publicize the tag's existence to people who are experts in that area but haven't seen questions about it (because obscure means low volume).  Or, on a site where we make it easy to link off-site blogs and Twitter accounts in your profile, it's a way to say "this *on-site* content might interest you, too".