# Help us identify micro-privileges for top users

Tags: feature-request, privileges

Are you familiar with tapas?

[image: Pincho moruno] [image: Chorizo a la sidra] [image: Aceitunas] [image: Boquerones] [image: Croquetas] [image: Gambas]

These are little appetizers invented in Spain that people enjoy while talking and drinking in the cool of the evening. What makes them so great is that you get a wide variety of tastes without getting fed up.

Not long ago, I asked for suggestions of a new [30k privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get). As presented, I was asking for a big meal at 30k. For this question, I'm looking for unlockables that could be spread around reputation levels like tapas dishes.  To give you an idea of what I mean, here's one we are considering:

> ### Access to site analytics
>
> Community moderators have access to a page that includes several interactive charts showing time series of aggregate data such as traffic, posts, page views, and even newsletter subscriptions.  Much of it can be cobbled together via public sources, such as [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but not all of it and not all in one place. Traditionally we haven't shown this data to non-moderators because there's not a lot people can do with it.
>
> But there's no reason users with X reputation couldn't have access to those statistics. Conceivably, it could even be useful for community leaders to have better data about their site's history collected in one place. More importantly, however, it's an amusement people could look forward to earning.

Micro-privileges should:

1. Be desirable for people who have been active on the site for a long time,
2. Not add significant responsibilities for those earning them<sup>*</sup>, and
3. Not cause any problems for other people using the site.

What tasty dish would you like to serve to high-reputation users?

---

<sup>*</sup> Quite a few of the 30k suggestions are [moderator privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get#comment825226_252711) which mean you *get* to do something that, in turn, *could become an obligation*. This is one of the things that makes me uncomfortable about giving 30k users the burden of moderating comments.

Comment: Share some ad revenue

Comment: Just to nitpick on your last paragraph, I don't believe moderator privileges should be a *burden*. If high-rep users want to continue providing great content and nothing else, let them do it.

Comment: Question: On beta sites, when would users unlock these privileges?

Comment: @HDE226868: Maybe. The analytics view makes a lot of sense for beta sites, for instance. But we'd probably want to keep the reputation levels constant for more cosmetic items.

Comment: @JonEricson I would support 6,000 reputation being the threshold for analytics on beta sites. It's consistent with being 1.5 times the "trusted user" level.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to bind useful and harmless features to only a subset of users. The 1k reputation requirement for observing vote counts is extremely annoying on sites where I am not registered or don't have sufficient reputation. Is there any reason why the site analytics should not be a completely public feature?

Comment: As a glutton, I resent tapas.

Comment: @copy, it wouldn't be appropriate to share millions of dollars of revenue with contributing users not making any income.

Comment: Allow 30k to use footnotes ;-)

Comment: @Arjan You can make hand-crafted footnotes with `<sup></sup>` and `---`. And I don't really see why such an ability would be restricted to high rep users...

Comment: @Najib, if I thought it answered the question, I'd have posted it as an answer, and left out the smiley... That said, handcrafting foot notes is not a good solution, I feel, so whenever a Stack Exchange employee does that, I like to point that out to them. Eric, remember your [*"it's still a pain and the results aren't ideal"*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes/166518#166518)? Use your powers! ;-)

Comment: (Sorry, Jon, that "Eric" should read Jon in my off-topic comment above...)

Comment: Uh, I've read that question two times now but still have a hard time seeing the difference to your previous 30k privilege question. What is it you're actually looking for, privileges that shouldn't just apply to 30kers but also lower ones? Or prvileges that should be *somehow* smaller than the ones presented previously? Does this mean the previous 30k privilege question has failed somehow and is now considered obsolete? Sorry if those are stupid questions, but I try to understand what the purpose of this question actually is, already knowing what tapas are didn't really help me here.

Comment: I agree with the top comment on that other question you link: please stay away from moderation features. (In fact, it may be useful to overhaul the moderation privileges so that they depend on useful moderation activity instead of content provided.)

Comment: There's some pretty good stuff in here. Could we get an update with some movement on any of them?  (I mean the ones not marked as status-completed)

Comment: @Won't: Thanks for the prodding. I've been tracking these for when I have bandwidth to do something about them. SInce it's been, what, half a year since I suggested this, it's _waaaaay_ past time to provide my feedback. So I've started to leave edits below.

Comment: @JonEricson *thank you* for saying *why* you chose what you chose for everything! :)

Comment: Any chance of a "winter holiday of your choice" gift of a "status-planned" on the [top-voted not-yet-completed proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253687/162102)?  (Will Jon even see this comment, given that hat? :-) )

Comment: @JonEricson can I get a ruling on this one, either way? Seems to have support: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258814/163135

Answer (score 160):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) *Dec. 9, 2015*

*Implemented for 10k users, 2k on beta sites*

*See: [Enable searching with deleted:1 for 10k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users)*

---

### Ability to use the `deleted:0`, `deleted:1`, `deleted:all` search queries

Currently, these are only available to moderators. This is a feature that I miss dearly on sites where I'm not a mod.

This would also allow users to view a list of all their own deleted posts (search `deleted:1 user:me`), essentially making it a more powerful version of [bluefeet's request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253671/180276).

Keeping this... relatively less prominent, for lack of better wording, as a search query and not as a link, would also help with users who would abuse the feature to whine and complain about everything. (Similarly to how it's really possible to view split vote counts before earning the privilege, but simply not advertising this is sufficient to prevent excess load on the server.)

Comment: "(Similarly to how it's really possible to view split vote counts before earning the privilege, but simply not advertising this is sufficient to prevent excess load on the server.)" Wait, really? How?

Comment: @JoeZ. You can manually send the GET request (through `XMLHttpRequest` or `$.get` in your browser console), and there's no server-side check to see if you really have 1k rep. (There's also a convenience script on Stack Apps, which I won't link here but can easily be found via a simple search.)

Comment: Had to show me up, huh?

Comment: Basically [my request for 30k users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252786/259693)?

Comment: I still haven't read a single convincing argument for why this should be accessible to everyone. What exactly would you do with that information? (Besides, this looks like a huge privilege, not really in the spirit of this thread.)

Comment: Do you intend this to also allow for the search of *other* user's deleted posts? It seems you're taking @bluefeet's suggestion and adding a whole lot more power to it (not that it's ever likely to affect me).

Comment: This is a three-course dinner, not a tapa.

Comment: Wouldn't this make sense as an addition to the [10k level](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) which includes the ability to view (and vote to undelete) posts?

Comment: @JonEricson As to the `status-completed`, am I right that it is only half-way completed, since it only shows *your own* deleted things or have I misinterpreted that linked meta answer?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Correct. Though, if you were quick, you could have [searched other people's posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270554/1438). That hole has been patched.

Answer (score 157):

### Show off the posts I'm most proud of

Give users a place on the profile<sup>1</sup> (Profile rather than Activity; this is outward-facing) to collect, say, up to 10 posts that they're most proud of or otherwise want to show off.  Sometimes your best work isn't high-scoring (maybe it's in an obscure, low-traffic tag), or maybe you just think everything *clicked* on that post and you want to show it off a little.

Ideally you would be able to click on an "add to my list" control next to any of your posts (with a warning if you're already at the max number).  But if that's too hard, a place to paste in a URL to add it to the list would be ok.  It'd be nice if you could change the order, but that's not critical; I'm imagining a list short enough to easily browse, after all.

This idea was inspired by the part of the Careers profile where you can advertise selected answers from across the network.  (And I imagine reusing some code from there.)  My proposal includes questions and not just answers, because a well-asked question can be a thing of beauty too.  And my proposal is tied to a particular site, both selection and viewing; I see this being about "my best work *here*", not "my best work in a job hunt" or "my best work for all viewers in all contexts".

Yes, people can build this themselves, using the "projects" or "about me" areas, but this is meant to (a) make it easier and (b) plant the idea.  (People *can* do this in other ways, but how many think to do it?)

<sup>1</sup> Maybe by adding a "My Picks" tab to the "Top Posts" section (next to All, Questions, Answers, etc), like this:

[image: Mockup]

This list you see now contains up to 10 items, which is why I propose up to 10 "picks".  That would use the space already allocated to showing a selection of posts.

Comment: This is a good idea for feature for all users, don't think it'd go over to well for only high rep users.

Comment: This. My answers on human sacrifice & cannibalism (on History.SE) is the first thing I want people to notice when visiting my profile.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 from the question: "I'm looking for unlockables that could be spread around reputation levels like tapas dishes."  People seem to be assuming these would be 30k+, but it doesn't actually say that and I'm not assuming it in my answer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio To be honest I don't actually know what I'm supposed to assume this question is asking for, since I didn't really get its purpose at all. But nevertheless this would be a great feature.

Comment: @Christian thanks. I suspect the purpose Is open brainstorming, but that's a guess.

Comment: I like this, but I think 10 might be too many; we don't have that much real-estate as it is. I would maximize it at 3 pinned questions, 3 pinned answers.

Comment: @TylerH there are 10 items in the "top posts" section now, which is why I chose that number -- if this is another "tab" in that section of the page, that's a number that already fits.  I don't see any reason to constrain the mix of questions and answers; if somebody wants to show off mostly answers (or mostly questions), why not?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Because too much content is noise and when it's all below the fold, it's just wasted.

Comment: @TylerH I've updated the post to show more clearly how this fits into the existing profile design.  My proposal uses the same amount of space (on a different "tab") as the current design; it doesn't push anything below the fold.  If SE wants to tweak the number that's fine (I did say "say, 10", suggesting it's flexible); I just think that number fits.  We don't need to quibble over 10 vs 8 or whatever, though.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms, thanks for the graphical contribution!

Comment: @Yannis I'm somehow not surprised at that.

Comment: I've suggested an alternative implementation idea: [edit the top network questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269998/300411).

Comment: WHAT A GREAT IDEA! WHY AREN'T WE ALREADY DOING THIS?!

Answer (score 120):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) *Sep. 7, 2015*:

*Implemented for 25k users on graduated sites and 5k users on beta sites.*

---

I absolutely love the example suggestion. So here it is so that it may be voted on.

> ### Access to site analytics
>
> Community moderators have access to a page that includes several interactive charts showing time series of aggregate data such as traffic, posts, page views, and even newsletter subscriptions.  Much of it can be cobbled together via public sources, such as [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but not all of it and not all in one place. Traditionally we haven't shown this data to non-moderators because there's not a lot people can do with it.
>
> But there's no reason users with X reputation couldn't have access to those statistics. Conceivably, it could even be useful for community leaders to have better data about their site's history collected in one place. More importantly, however, it's an amusement people could look forward to earning.

Comment: Yes! Very often I come across something with a lot of traffic and I'm unable to find where it is coming from. Sometimes it's obvious if it's on Reddit or HN, but most of the time, I'm left guessing.

Comment: Shouldn't the OP answer with that himself?

Comment: As I [commented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253668/help-us-identify-micro-privileges-for-top-users#comment828514_253668) on the main post: "I think it's a bad idea to bind useful and harmless features to only a subset of users. The 1k reputation requirement for observing vote counts is extremely annoying on sites where I am not registered or don't have sufficient reputation. Is there any reason why the site analytics should not be a completely public feature?"

Comment: @corsair992 if I recall correctly, the privilege was put in place because it costs too much on server side, and most (like ~50%) of users are under 1k. You wouldn't give metal pipes to monkeys around your car, will you?

Comment: @Braiam: Then the system is badly implemented, and should have been optimized to retain this data along with the aggregated total. A badly optimized system should inspire optimization, not patching.

Comment: @Braiam Jeff Atwood made a lot of excuses like that, many of which were unfounded. I trust that Stack Exchange's engineers could make it work without much difficulty, if they wanted to, but now it's a *thing* the way it is.

Comment: @PythonMaster I'm guessing Jon didn't want to post it himself to prevent it from having an unfair FGITW advantage? Regardless, I've asked him in chat before posting, and he said it was fine by him.

Comment: I think it's a bit silly to have official statistics for high-rep users and (inevitable) meta posts linking to analogous SEDE queries for the rabble.  Being transparent even to low-rep users will help address charges of elitism and may get curious users interested in community moderation.

Comment: @corsair992, there is a Greasemonkey script which lets you see vote counts no matter what your rep is. See http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

Comment: @JonasCz: Thanks, I was aware of the script, and already have the Chrome extension installed.

Answer (score 109):

### See a list of inbound links to your questions and answers

On occasion, I'll run in to someone referring to my questions or answers out "in the wild" -- kind of neat! It isn't easy to get at that kind of information without manually searching Google; as a privilege it would be awesome to see a list of inbound links to things I've posted (including questions on SE that were closed against mine as a duplicate or links from comments). This is a subset of analytics data -- referrers other than Google. It would also be cool, and in the same vein, to see a list of top Google search terms that lead to my posts.

These data points don't add any special functionality, or introduce a capability that could be considered a burden. Just a little sop for ego, and possibly a way to join conversations elsewhere regarding a subject that you've dealt with, either as answer author or as a frustrated developer who posted a question.

Thanks for considering adding a new privilege!

Comment: Yes, please!  Every now and then I notice something suddenly getting a burst of attention and I wonder "where did that get linked?".

Comment: Yes! Though I'd love to see this at a lower rep (selfishly).

Comment: This happens to me all the time: I'll have a 3-yr-old post suddenly get three votes in the same day. I'd love to be able to know what triggered that, so I can engage with that audience. I've asked for this before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99042/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-referrers-for-a-specific-question/99058#99058

Answer (score 98):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Nov. 12, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*This seems like a useful addition to search. I don't know if it makes sense to limit this to any particular reputation level however. If we do index comments for search, we might as well let anyone use the feature.*

*At the moment, we are using a version of [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html) that makes mixing commments with posts difficult/impossible. It's possible that when we upgrade to 2.x this feature could be implemented. But that's a ways off. So I'm declining this feature request until then.*

---

### Search comments

Often enough to be frustrating, I remember either seeing or *making* a comment that I'd like to find again -- a helpful reference, a well-written comment that I'd like to use as a template, something involving weaponized unicorns that made me laugh out loud, whatever.  If I know who posted it I can painstakingly dig through the "actions" tab from a profile, or I suppose I could try to find it with the LIKE operator in SEDE (if it's old enough).  But why not make that easier?

Comments are second-class objects for good reasons and aren't <strike>indexed by Google</strike> generally searchable on-site, but I don't see the harm in making it a little easier for established users to find them.

I don't mean mingling comments with posts in general search; that could produce a lot of noise.  I mean supporting a directive like `is:comment` (to go along with `is:question` and `is:answer`) to search comments intentionally.

Comment: This would be helpful in so many ways.

Comment: Google does index comments. I use it all the time for searching them.

Comment: @tchrist they do?  Hmm, I haven't had much luck with that.  I'll take another look.  (Still, if I could do it *on-site*, that'd be even better!)

Comment: This is another one that shouldn't only be available to high-rep users.  This should be available to all users.

Comment: @pacoverflow from the question: "I'm looking for unlockables that could be spread around reputation levels like tapas dishes."  People seem to be assuming these would be 30k+, but it doesn't actually say that and I'm not assuming it in my answer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Why should there be any reputation requirement at all on a simple functional non-harmful site feature?

Comment: @corsair992 Similar to view vote counts. It's just a lot of server strain if everyone gets to do it.

Comment: @Scimonster: Indexing the comments as well as the questions and answers should take up at most twice the space. Just like the argument for restricting vote counts, this is also a bad argument. Any such costs should be measured and considered in detail with a cost-benefit analysis, _before_ using them as a vague argument for restricting all but the most essential features. I doubt it will be used that much anyway, if introduced as a separate feature from the general search.

Comment: Comments often include (or are) links to other topics. If you search for keywords in a topic title with this feature enabled, the search results will include not just questions, but also answers (which is already more than you want) and furthermore comments too.

Comment: @ChrisW I didn't mean we should mix comments into search results willy-nilly; I agree that could add noise.  I was thinking of a specific directive, e.g. is:comment, so you could search comments *intentionally*.  I've edited that in.

Comment: I'm using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73775/search-my-own-comments). It's pretty clear how to change it to search not only comments of a particular user.

Comment: Thanks @TLama!  This definitely helps with comments that are older than the time of the last data dump, which covers many of the cases.

Comment: @JohEricson, if searching comments doesn't burden the site in some way, then I agree it would be useful to have for everybody.

Comment: @JonEricson re the decline -- bummer, but if the devs can't do it with the current architecture, I can't exactly ask them to make magic happen. :-)  One question, though: were they looking at searching both posts *and* comments in a single search?  That's not what I was asking for; I proposed searching *only* comments (instead of the default of searching *only* posts) if you use the enabling syntax.  I suspect that mixing comments in with posts on general searches would be pretty noisy.

Comment: Ah. I was ambiguous. If I understand the situation, mixing them so that comments turn up in a regular search would be easier. It's the very fact that we need to keep them somewhat separate that causes the problem. There are probably workarounds (I'm guessing a separate index for comments could be built and hacked in), but we'd prefer to wait for the upgrade that will support it properly.

Comment: @JonEricson thanks.  I agree that hacking it in now when an upgrade later would let you do it right would not be a great idea.

Comment: @JonEricson revisit this perhaps? :)

Comment: @JonEricson hi, is this being looked at now? It’s been a really long time.

Answer (score 87):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) *Dec. 9, 2015*

*Implemented for 10k users, 2k on beta sites*

*See: [Enable searching with deleted:1 for 10k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users)*

You can use this feature by using search `deleted:1 user:me`.

---

Original by Jon Ericson:

> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) (Jon Ericson)
>
> *I love the idea. But I'm afraid that high reputation users are not immune from being annoyed by their deleted posts (either because they love them and wish they were undeleted or hate seeing the follies of their past selves). If anything, I'd rather lift this restriction for everyone than make it a privilege.*

---

## The ability to view your deleted posts regardless of age

From our profile page for questions and answers, we get access to the recently deleted content, stuff deleted in the past 60 days. I propose removing this limitation and allowing us access to all of our deleted posts.

Comment: I don't see why this should be related to rep.

Comment: @bjb568 Seconded. This would be nice to have at any level.

Comment: We don't need any more "view vote count" privileges.

Comment: @bjb [It was prophesied](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/259867) that this ability "would result in unbearable amounts of wailing, gnashing of teeth, meta complaints, Twitter rants, cats sleeping with dogs, CHAOS..." Restricting access to a small subset of users would mitigate that.

Comment: @pizza There are many ways to define a small subset of users besides rep.

Comment: I don't see what your age has to do... oh. Wait.

Comment: Even the 60-day window has generated a certain amount of noise from folks who absolutely cannot *stand* that their deleted posts are still in the system, regardless of visibility. I'd want to put a lot more thought into this before considering it.

Comment: @Shog9 But those would be the folks relatively new to the system? By 30K or so, one has to get used to how deletion works.

Comment: One of the folks who soured me on it had 22K, @pizza - I'm skeptical.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this proposal just because this really should be accessible to all users, and establishing it as a reputation privilege makes it less likely that that will ever happen. High-reputation users aren't the only ones who put lots of effort into posts and don't deserve to have them lost.

Comment: If the `deleted:` searches are enabled, then this comes along with it but only for interested users: `user:me deleted:?` - So I'd simply rather have that enabled.  Then those users who want to see their own deleted stuff can, and it doesn't appear on their private page.

Comment: **Yes please.** Deleted questions **and** answers to deleted questions.

Comment: @JonEricson This is now status-completed, because you implemented deleted:1 user:me

Comment: @wythagoras you don't need the `user:me`, unless you have a diamond.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just adding user:me for completeness sake, in case it once will change (i.e. that you can see all deleted posts)

Comment: @wythagoras well, we can actually but this is most likely a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Can you clarify?

Comment: @wythagoras [just see for yourself](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A2+deleted%3Aall). (actually I can't see it myself having less than 10k there, but hope you get the point now :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard I get: "Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content". I'm quite sure this is intentional, not a bug.

Comment: @wythagoras that's because Geoff doesn't have any deleted posts on that site. Try with other user, and you will see his/her deleted posts. (you will see ALL posts, but including deleted posts) Just to prove it's working, I found [this deleted question of yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263616/minor-bug-i-found-some-english-words-on-the-rus-stackexchange-site) just now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This is really weird. If I search for `deleted:1 user:6000` I get my own deleted posts, but if I search for `deleted:all user:6000`, I get all user:6000's posts, including his deleted posts.

Comment: @wythagoras yes I know. The bug is when you put anything but 1 as the value of "deleted" operator. For what's it's worth, the bug is [already reported for 8 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/10k-users-can-still-search-any-users-deleted-content), without any hint of attention.

Answer (score 70):

#### New flair themes

Currently, only a small number distinguishes a top user's flair from any other.

New flairs, available only to high reputation users, could have a more elaborate design, with color pattern emphasizing value (compare to credit cards: gold, platinum, etc).

Comment: Bad keming had me reading this as New Hair Themes, which I thought would be almost as much fun as hats. Darn. :)

Comment: Or just let them define the colors via URL variables. There's only a few colors that actually change between flair themes.

Comment: @animuson  That's not very exciting though... I imagined VIP flair as being different in more than just the colors - having a unicorn  or "SE MVP" seal or something like that.

Comment: Do you mean flair specifically, or the usercard in general (e.g. what shows up when you post)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I mean the flair, which is used to show off one's profile off-site. I wouldn't want this on the site -- I much prefer uniformity of user cards.

Comment: @tchrist Bad kerning, incidentally, had me reading your comment as "bag keming" :P

Answer (score 57):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Oct. 23, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*Let me preface this by saying that I've never hit this limit myself. I have hit other rate limits that are annoying, so I'm imagining what it would be like to hit this limit fairly often. To be candid, I don't think chat moderation tools are ready to handle problems of annoying, but not exactly abusive behavior. Personally, I'd rather people post full thoughts in a single chat message and slow down a bit. I believe that's part of the reason for including this limit.*

---

### Reduced or removed rate limit in chat

We already trust anyone with enough reputation to chat to post two messages in succession. Nothing bad could come out of that. But allowing people to post *three* messages in a row? **Three whole messages?!** Just *think* of the unspeakable evil that could come out of that!!

In all seriousness, hitting the rate limit once every ten messages is extremely annoying, especially when I can hop over to, say, IRC, and post messages without restraint. We already have a flagging system, which should take care of cases of users abusing the system by posting many useless messages in a row. A gradually reducing rate limit as you gain rep wouldn't cause too much harm and would make many chatters' lives much, much less painful an- aa**ahug*guh*gh**g**hu***gh* what do you *MEAN* I have to wait *TEN MORE SECONDS* just to *finish a complete thought*?!!!??!

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: IRC has a restraint. You don't see it. IRC will throttle your messages and induce lag on purpose. If you post too much too fast, the server will terminate you with "Excess Flood".

Comment: @SecondRikudo True, but unlike Stack Exchange chat, I can at the very least post more than two messages in a row.

Comment: @Doorknob given that chat works mainly on WebSockets now as opposed to the old polling system, I guess the restrictions can be made more lenient. But I'm not sure how the internal stuff works.

Comment: @tchrist It would probably not be a bad idea if it were a privilege gained at 10k or 20k.

Comment: As a regular chat user, yes please. I understand some kind of anti-spam mechanism is needed, but a bit more leniency after a certain rep treshold would be very welcome.

Comment: I propose (rep/1000) + 2 messages in a row.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it has the ability to. It doesn't have to. Just nitpicking.

Comment: The character limit for chat messages is huge. Anybody hitting this limit can just expand their thoughts in each messages rather than spewing incomplete bits in separate messages. The rate limit is already generous enough that even the fastest typists are never going to hit it and you can post whole walls of text in a row, you just need to hit enter less often. Send messages after whole sentences or paragraphs rather than after each word and you'll be golden.

Comment: The difference is that IRC's flood limit is often quite liberal. On some popular networks, you are allowed to send 10 lines (512 bytes in size, including nickname, channel, and command) in a single burst, and then all subsequent lines must be 0.5 or 1 second apart. Of course, many bots with chanop will have their own custom thresholds for individual channels. Of course, then the bots might get lag and then ban everyone who was talking because it thinks that the incoming burst is spam...

Answer (score 55):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Oct. 23, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*I find the topbar notifications very compelling; it's difficult to let them sit unclicked. My amateur behavioral psychology suggests that only showing positive changes is a big reason. It's not that this idea wouldn't be useful. Rather, it works against the original purpose of the feature: engage users when they do positive things on the sites. For a subset of people (even high-reputation users) the aggravation seeing the occasional downvote displayed prominently would be a turn-off.*

---

## Show downvotes in the topbar notification area

You know, this one: [Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements)

Big kids don't need the truth hidden from them.

Comment: Big kids do need the truth hidden from them. That's why we have the 60 days/+3 rule http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124799/clarifying-the-criteria-for-when-rep-from-deleted-posts-is-maintained/124805#124805

Comment: I'm not sure I see the relevance to your link. I'm not talking about rep from deleted posts. Just seeing downvotes on own posts and such. See linked Q

Comment: He's saying even folks with lots of rep can be sensitive about small changes, @mhlester.

Comment: This should be available to all users, especially new users.  New users need to know when they have posted something of low quality, so they can improve it and learn and become more productive users of SE.  High-rep users already know to click on that achievements drop-down every 10 minutes. ;)

Comment: @pacoverflow you're not wrong, but click the linked feature request for the drawn out debate about it culminating in the status-declined. Hopefully an unlockable privilege would be more palatable. I agree most of the requests here could benefit all users.

Comment: @JonEricson, the lack of notifications wouldn't be so annoying (at least to me) if they didn't mask *positive* notifications.  A "-40 user was removed" should not block me from seeing the +10s and +5s from upvotes on posts, but currently it does.  Any chance of at least fixing that?

Comment: Related to my previous comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209467/162102

Answer (score 51):

I don't know if this question is still active, but...

## Give users an `@sitename.stackexchange.com` email

I'm (relatively) not that active on Stack Exchange, but I've engaged in email correspondence with other users. I use email because, unlike chat, it's not public and it encourages in depth messages (e.g. no length limit). I use a gmail account when I do this. I might be an anomaly, but I suspect that this would be useful for a lot of people, especially moderators (who might use it to email people to ask them to promote the site).

It would be really cool if Stack Exchange would give moderators and/or high-rep users a `@sitename.stackexchange.com` email. I don't know how hard that would be to implement, but it would be a really cool feature for the small subset of users who use email.

Comment: It's still active and I'm reading answers as they come in. Unfortunately, we have limited bandwidth for this particular project right at the moment. I really like this particular idea. The primary concern raised internally was that `user@stackexchange.com` is the format of our employee email addresses, which might be confusing or deceptive. I had not thought about tying the email to particular sites, but that has promise. It would also be particularly straightforward to implement as a redirect. (Though I do recall some technical concerns. Hmmmm...)

Comment: @JonEricson two alternative ideas. (1) I know that many colleges give alumni email addresses that end in `@alumni.harvard.edu`, maybe Stack Exchange could use something like `@contributor.stackexchange.com`? Or, since Stack Exchange has been renamed to Stack Overflow, maybe the employee emails should end in `@stackoverflow.com` while users could get the `@stackexchange.com` email addresses.

Comment: No. You don't want unknown people to have an SE.com mail, do you? Also, you can have a zillion users with the same display name, and also you can change your display name at any time.

Comment: @yo' they wouldn't be "unknown people", they would be people who are moderators or who have 30K reputation.

Comment: @Hamlet They are unknown in the sense that they can be whoever they wish and communicate with anybody using their stackexchange mail. You wouldn't expect, when communicating with someone whose address is `johndoe@stackoverflow.com` that he's not a staff and StackOverflow. At least I would not. Whenever I communicate with someone with that address, I know it's an SE staff member; I don't have to check each time. I would like this to stay true.

Comment: What about something like, redirect-only with autoreply? So when someone sends a mail to arda@arqade.com etc, it gets redirected to my mail, and the sender of the mail gets a mail saying that the mail was delivered to me and states that I'm not a SE staff member.

Comment: @ardaozkal In other words, give away the user's private email address to anyone who asks?

Comment: @E.P. auto redirect != reply with private mail.

Comment: @ardaozkal It was the autoreply that bothered me but I see it now.

Comment: @yo' They could use the user IDs, for example.

Answer (score 49):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *Oct. 24, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*So I think showing deleted posts that you commented on will encourage useless (or barely useful) comments on deletable posts. If you are just commenting, you don't have any special stake in a post. (Now an edit, might be a different story.) For deleted questions you've answered and deleted answers to your question, I can see some value. I'm debating whether to decline this idea, but I think there's a possibility it might help more people than it bothers. The cases I'm most worried about are outrageously offensive answers to a question that stick around to aggravate you forever and encouraging people to answer bad questions rather than downvote them. There are ways around this (don't show posts deleted as offensive, for instance), but it starts to get complicated.*

*So I'm going to think about this idea a bit more.*

---

You did not specify, how high “high reputation” is here, so you might consider the following suggestion for some reputation level before 10 k (say 4 k) “off-topic”:

### See deleted posts under some conditions

#### In general:

I sometimes want to check the progress of my efforts to improve posts by editing, teaching the poster on using the site or asking the poster about specific unclarities. On sites, where I have not reached 10 k, if the post got deleted, this may result in me searching for a while and just not finding it, which can be quite annoying. Thus it would be nice to be able to see deleted posts, on which I participated in some way.

#### In particular:

- **See deleted questions (and answers to them) if you posted an answer to the question yourself.** This is particularly annoying if I post an elaborate answer to a question, which then gets deleted for no apparent reason (e.g., by a user misunderstanding the system). In this case, I have no easy means of salvaging my answer.
- **See deleted answers to your own question.** If an answer gets deleted, this is usally for a good reason. But if you ask a question, it’s sometimes useful to have an overview of the whole story.
- **See any deleted posts on which you commented** – for the general reasons described above.

Comment: This should preferably be applied for all users, or at least at a very low rep threshold (say 500 or 250). If you have interacted with the post, then it should not be hidden from you (along with potentially your own contribution).

Comment: It's particularly frustrating to get a notification for a new answer to my own question, only to not be able to see it when I go there.

Comment: @corsair992 from the question: "I'm looking for unlockables that could be spread around reputation levels like tapas dishes."  People seem to be assuming these would be 30k+, but it doesn't actually say that and I'm not assuming it for answers here.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: The answer suggested 4k reputation to be an appropriate threshold, and I was responding to that. I don't think there would be much harm (and a great deal of benefit) in introducing this feature for everyone without _any_ requirements or privilege levels.

Comment: @corsair992: There could be reasons we are unware of, e.g., [seeing vote counts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) is restricted to 1000 reputation due to the database queries involved. Moreover, while I do not see a reason right now why this should not be introduced on a much lower level, I do not think that this feature should be available to brand new users, who have yet to learn what a deleted post is.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: The vote counts argument was a particularly bad excuse - it could have been easily optimized to be part of the initial query instead of the aggregate total. It seems a bad idea to block useful and essential features from a large part of the userbase unless there is some (actual and not just perceived) good reason for doing that which outweighs the benefits that it would provide.

Comment: @JonEricson: Thanks for your evaluation. Do you really think that people would comment on posts just to be able to see them when they are deleted? If it helps, this suggestion could be regarded as a step-by-step unlocking of the see-deleted-posts part of the 10 k privilege (and thus fill the huge gap between 3 k and 10 k), e.g.: 4 k: see deleted questions you answered; 7 k: see deleted posts that you edited; 8.5 k; see deleted posts that you commented on; 10 k see all deleted posts. As for spam/offensive posts: Isn’t their content hidden by default anyway and needs to be unlocked by a click?

Answer (score 41):

### Remove nofollow from links which the user posts

It's to be hoped that the user posts high-quality, relevant links.

If they begin to spam there are other (more severe than adding 'nofollow') ways to deal with that.

See *[Remove nofollow on links deemed reputable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111279/139866)*

---

See also [Can we not rel=nofollow links in profile About Me for users with 3000+ rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6905/139866)

---

See also *[Stackoverflow amongst nofollow web abuse sites](https://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/104/)* (caveat: this seems to me an interesting point of view on this subject however I don't know whether it's true).

Comment: This would improve SE's internet SEO karma, which I believe will then in turn provide the entire SE staff with free backlink shawarma.

Comment: I thought this happened already for everyone over something quite low like 1,000. Now I think about it though, I have no idea where I got that idea. Maybe I just made it up. It seems like a good idea, if it was implemented, no-one would start saying "we should start `rel=nofollow`ing our top users' posts"

Comment: I don't see how this is really a privilege for the user, particularly because you shouldn't be posting links to your own site all the time (if you even have one—most people don't). Plus there are times when you need to link to sites you may not want to give juice to (such as for a [notable claim](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2506/37236) on Skeptics).

Comment: I believe the privilege should be the option to decide what links to have with nofollow.

Answer (score 38):

## View vote counts on any site

The main (only?) reason that view vote counts is a privilege and not open to anyone is server load. I find it very irritating that I can not view vote counts on sites I've not (yet) reached 1,000 reputation, which is quite much.

I suggest that users who have ever reached some threshold (4k?) on some site, get the ability to see vote counts on any site. This would just be some checkmark that is ticked on and never ticked off, like the association bonus.

This would only cause a small extra server load, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: [Shhh, don't tell anyone but there's a script for that.](http://stackapps.com/q/3082/17253)

Comment: @terdon - When I load a page that I can check the counts on, does it load them in the background anyway, or only when I click on them? Because rarely do I actually check them even if I can. It's usually only when I think there's some funny business going on. Like trying to track down which answer the DV'er *didn't* DV (which in turn usually helps me find the DV'er - perhaps that's another reason why we can't). Side note: no one is getting a bounty from me, from a site I will then end up with less than 1k. I will also reduce myself to begging for UV if I have 980 rep. <yuck>

Comment: I'll admit I'm too lazy to look. Anyone care to link to where "everyone can see them" is status-declined?

Comment: I like the idea of 30K users on one site not having to earn some of the "informational" privileges on any SE site. They should still have to earn the privileges that impact the site's content (not having their edits peer-reviewed for example).

Answer (score 37):

#### Custom URL for profile page

E.g.  `{site}/users/firstname-lastname` or whatever the user wants. It would be just a redirect, but some users might like it. (Indeed, this [is requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254392/259867) occasionally.)

Comment: I really like this idea, but it seems pretty elitist and widens the gulf between the experts and the newbies. Still, as far as bling goes it's going to  be fairly attractive to users.

Answer (score 35):

## The ability to see your deleted comments.

I've had a few times recently when I go back and look at a post and think, "I should add a certain comment to this", then think, "but didn't I already *do* that?", and "maybe it's been deleted", and "But if it has been deleted, then I can't *see* that it's been deleted", so "I guess I won't add that comment, since it will only be deleted again".

Answer (score 31):

## More Up/Down Votes

The high rep-users are regularly online, and find plenty of ***really good*** or ***really bad*** posts to vote on. As a result, they frequently run out. Higher rep users should have many more than 40 votes per day. I frequently use all of my daily votes, and I am sure there are plenty of other users that would also enjoy more daily votes.

Answer (score 30):

Decorate tags with our tag badges. That is, where the tags are shown below a question:

[image: tags]

Put a little dot on them just like tag badges:

[image: tags with dots]

Except that the shape would be like tags and not so square, I grabbed that from my "next badge" list on my profile. I would want this for all three colours of tag badge. It would be a fun reminder of the tag badges we have (too expensive for everyone, but there are fewer high rep users) and would take care of [reminding me about the dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/please-remind-me-when-i-am-wielding-the-dupe-hammer) while we're at it.

Comment: With the problem that the dupehammer is related to the Q's original tags, not the current tags, creating a discrepancy between what you see and what you get.

Comment: a **possible** discrepancy if the tags changed. Not the norm.

Comment: Still, a source of confusion. If the dupe hammer has to be marked, it should be marked clearly.

Comment: @yo' dupehammer rules have changed a little: it is now based on current tags with only the exception that **if the hammer holder added the tag** they don't get it. You could still draw the bronze/silver/gold dot on any and all tags, and if the person tries and fails to hammer based on a tag they added, it won't take long for them to figure that out.

Answer (score 29):

## Even fewer ads

Right now you show 4 ads, two inline, and two sidebar for new users, or users with under 200 reputation.

At 200 reputation you remove the inline ads, leaving two sidebar ads.

Consider removing one sidebar ad at some level (10k? 50k?) and the second (ad-free!) at 100k or 200k.

This will probably not alter your bottom line very much, and it will increase high-rep user engagement, since the related and hot network questions will now appear above the fold, enticing the high rep user to stay on the site and contribute more content.

If you can't get rid of the ads altogether, perhaps moving them further down in the sidebar as reputation increases would be sufficient.

Comment: I'm all for fewer ads, but I just don't see this happening. Surely all SO users with 100k rep use Adblock or userscripts that don't show the ads anyway. Less technical users who have 100k on a non-IT site might not, but since when has SE ever cared about those?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about SO?  I never see external ads on the sites I'm active on, just the SE and community-promotion ads -- and I want to see those.

Comment: I don't see adds on SO either. I just tested with Adblock disabled and I still didn't see any. What are these adds you speak of?

Comment: @MonicaCellio My expectation is that as they [move to the standard sidebar ad format](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites) they will increase their ad display.  Right now when they don't have ads to show, they show internal ads, such as area51, community promotion, and jobs. When they have external advertising, the internal ads compete.  My understanding is that the internal ads are not much more than placeholders, and will always lose out to paid advertising.

Comment: In principle, sure, but is anybody trying to *sell* ads for Skeptics or Mi Yodeya or Seasoned Advice?  I thought they weren't.

Comment: Would this principle be the same but lower rep points for beta sites? (like how the moderation system works)

Answer (score 28):

### Find interesting questions to answer

Sometimes I have some time available that I'd like to use to make my favorite sites better, but I feel like *writing*, not *moderating*, and the questions on the front page aren't grabbing me.  Usually at this point I'll start surfing by tag, but that's a little narrow and tedious.  What I'd really like at those times is a way to say "find me some questions that it'd be worthwhile for me to try to answer".  That is, questions that:

- I haven't already answered.
- Are in tags I've either marked as favorites or answered a lot in (so odds are that I'll be interested).
- Don't have good answers already (so odds are there's room for me to help).

Comment: I do this from time to time. It just takes some creative searching/querying.

Comment: It can be done with effort, but we could make it easier.

Comment: Great minds [think alike](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253680/158781). :D

Comment: Related, though I want to include the old neglected questions too.

Comment: Looks like this is already underway: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query. If this can be done better, I think the search should be available to all users.

Comment: @RetoKoradi oh, cool!

Comment: @RetoKoradi being able to tweak your version of that algorithim manually seems like a perfect high-rep mini-privilege - "I know I answer a lot of *these* questions, but I see enough of them already - actually I want to push the slider up for *that* tag"

Answer (score 23):

Add the ability to search for posts that have close votes (or don't have close votes) and delete votes, using all the other power of search parameters.

I don't think people having the ability to do a search `closevotes:4 [mytag]` would become an obligation. Also, searching *in the reverse* (`closevotes:0`) would really help a lot in tag cleanups "search for all questions in this tag that aren't yet in the queue" [Stack Overflow Example.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal) [Programmers Example.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/structured-tag-cleanup-initiative-phase-ii/7293#7293)

Searching for questions based on delete votes could be good, too. Example search on Stack Overflow: `score:-10..-5 hasaccepted:yes closed:yes duplicate:no deletevotes:1..2 [mytag]`

Answer (score 23):

### Do not add micro-privileges

Micro-privileges intrinsically fail criterion #1:

> Be desirable for people who have been active on the site for a long time

Micro-privileges are disappointing. This is particularly visible with one of the existing privileges, the 15k (3.5k on beta) privilege to protect questions. This is an oft-repeated scene:

> Sweet, I have 15k, I have a new privilege! Huh, what's a protected question?
>
> Hmm, ok. Let me go find a question to protect!
>
> Huh, why would I ever protect a question? What's the point? <Asks on meta or in chat>
>
> Pfff, that's disappointing. I waited so long for this privilege and it's basically useless!

(Or worse, #3 is go off and protect a question that shouldn't be.)

Most of the existing privileges have an effect that's visible immediately. You can observe them passively or quickly find a way to use them, at least if you participate in activities other than asking and answering.

- 100 and below: at this stage, with the discovery of new features, pretty much anything is new. Commenting at 50 makes a huge difference.
- 250: view close votes on your own questions. A common source of disappointment because it's often mistaken for “view close votes on any question”, due to the description.
- 500: access review queues.
- 1k: click on the score and see the breakdown.
- 2k: edit without supervision.
- 2.5k: honestly, who knows about this one? And even if you do, tag synonyms without moderator intervention are kinda mythical. But it's between two privileges that are relatively close, not like the fairly long droughts between 3k and 10k or between 10k and 20k.
- 3k: new close button on questions, reopen ability, close review queues.
- 5k: much more minor, but you'll start seeing tag wikis to review. Still a bit disappointing.
- 10k: see deleted questions, vote to delete questions, `/tools`, …
- 15k: disappoint!
- 20k: edit a tag wiki without supervision, delete button on negative-scoring answers

If you're going to add more privileges, please make them **substantial enough**. It should be a feature that can be experienced immediately, or at least soon after getting the privilege. It doesn't have to be an important feature, it can be a cosmetic one, but it should be one that lets the user validate their accomplishment by doing or seeing something.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment.  Many of the answers here are privileges I consider substantial -- curating selections to show off as my best work, having better access to content (see deletions, search comments), and some others are things that I would be quite happy to get -- way happier than "protect questions".

Comment: Filling in some of the more disappointing privileges seems like a good idea. I'm proposing a [mentoring system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262292/1438) that could, potentially, open up at 15k. A few of the ideas here (and on my 30k question) seem like natural complements to existing privileges. I'm going to see if we can augment some of the middle levels as we add new levels.

Comment: +1. I have never understood why protecting is 15k, and not 10k or 20k. It IMHO does not make any difference, and I agree, protection is a technical thing, almost as technical as the ability to see deleted answers.

Answer (score 22):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Oct. 24, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*The idea is a really good one. The problem is that making it work would require pulling in more features that have baggage we probably don't want to be burdened with. In particular, if you can edit comments, it's important that someone be able to track changes. The five minute window means there's not much opportunity to mislead people with edits. But if I can go back years later and edit a comment, it'll be easier to grief other users or sow confusion. At the moment, not even moderators can view comment changes; it requires access to the live database. In addition, it turns out that late comment edits are less tempting than you might imagine. I rarely use it.*

---

### Edit your own comments without time limit

Regular users can edit their own comments for about 5 minutes, then editing is disabled.

I suggest you remove that time-limit.

This is not a big privilege, but you did ask for a "micro-privilege".

Comment: And what to do with the time stamp and the order of the comments?

Comment: They stay where they are. There's a pencil icon added to say that the comment has been edited. This feature already exists: users can edit their own comments for 5 minutes; moderators can edit any comment any time. The new feature I'm suggesting is similar: superusers can edit their own comments any time.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize mods had that ninja-edit power.

Comment: I'd like to see *something* to address the confusion or disruption that can be caused by editing a comment that someone else has replied to.  A timestamp in the tooltip on that edit icon showing the last-edit time would be sufficient.  I just want it to be possible for people to see that it happened if something happens in the thread to raise the question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio That would be a new feature wouldn't it? And are you worried that this feature could be abused if it were available to superusers? I assumed superusers were trusted.

Comment: Even superusers can, very occasionally, do unfortunate things, or rage-quit, or something.  I don't expect we would need this very often, but I'm not prepared to say the number is 0 so I'd like to have *some* mitigation there.  I'm hoping that pushing the information that must be already available into a tooltip would be a minor bit of work to enable your proposal.

Comment: I'd suggest not *removing* the time limit, but *extending* the time limit, say to 30 minutes or 1 hour.  I've had a number of occasions when I was collecting an appropriate link or the like and ran just over the 5 minute deadline.

Comment: It’s not only about superusers doing unfortunate things, it’s also adding confusion. Users do not expect comments to change, in particular old ones. Learning how Stack Exchange works is quite confusing already, having to learn that users with some high reputation level can edit comments whenever they want adds to this confusion.

Comment: What I could agree with is allowing priviledged users to edit their comment for one hour or similar if it is the most recent comment. This way no confusion can arise due to comments in the middle of a discusion changing. As one can already do this by plainly deleting and reposting the comment, this is however indeed a microfeature.

Comment: I suggest permanently allowing minor edits at least (as determined by an algorithm). a minor edit might be like this ("I relly disagree" to "I really disagree"), a quick fix that you missed during the first five min.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms You don't need to correct typos in something as unimportant as a comment, do you?

Comment: @yo' sometimes a missing 2 letter word, or an extra letter can make a comment virtually unintelligible, or change the meaning.

Answer (score 22):

<sup>Rather a nano- than a microprivilege:</sup>

#### Questions become immune to “tumbleweed” roomba deletion

Your questions are not affected by the following [deletion rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/255554) anymore:

> The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after 365 days.

Rationale: If you managed to reach a high reputation, your questions deserve the benefit of doubt for being remotely reasonable. Thus, if they match the above criteria, they are likely to be difficult-to-answer questions on a topic so niche that people do not even look at the question.

Comment: I just ran through my deleted questions and many of them indeed are tumbleweed answerable questions on border topics.

Comment: I've seen some very high-rep uses incessantly posting terrible questions. "If you managed to reach a high reputation, your questions deserve the benefit of doubt for being remotely reasonable." is simply not true.

Answer (score 19):

## Unfreeze recently auto-frozen chat rooms

Moderators often get a message whether they want to unfreeze a chat room. I propose that users beyond a certain threshold can unfreeze auto-frozen chat rooms that were freezed less than two weeks after they want to unfreeze the room. Since it are mainly high rep users who talk in chat, this is an useful feature.

The recent requirement might be removed but I think we should keep things in control.

Answer (score 18):

## See anonymous score<sup>1</sup> for a post

This is an extension to the view vote counts privilege.

If you have this privilege, you can, after clicking vote counts, click another time to see the number of anonymous upvotes and anonymous downvotes.

<sup>1</sup> People who are not logged in, or have <15 rep or <125 rep in case of a downvote, change the anonymous score when voting. This is something that already exists, and the posts with the highest anonymous score were also included in the 2015 report.

Comment: I've always wondered what the anonymous votes were even used for...

Comment: Well, there is `{site}/tools/post-feedback` (probably 10k+) and the `PostFeedback` table in SEDE open to the public.

Answer (score 18):

## Ability to make small edits throughout the network, with community review

Personally, I currently have well over 100k network-wide, over 10k on three different sites, over 3k on another eight sites, and over 2k on another two sites. I currently have diamonds on two sites, and have had one on another where I left in good standing.

*And still, there's a gazillion sites where I can't be trusted to fix a simple typo in a post without jumping through hoops.*

If a user has earned a large amount of reputation on one or even a few sites, it's a decent bet that they know reasonably well how things work. So if they come across typos or other small errors in posts on sites where they haven't earned enough reputation to be able to make edits without community review, *at least waive the six-character minimum* for edits, but keep the requirement for community review in place.

If the edits are rejected in community review for being, say, not constructive, then this should trigger the proposed-edit ban already in place. The threshold for triggering the proposed-edit ban could be lowered if the user is exercising this privilege.

Users are allowed to have some number of pending suggested edits at a time; I think half a dozen pending suggested edits is allowed, but I could be wrong about the exact number. There's no reason why a user exercising this privilege couldn't have that threshold lowered, even to just one suggested edit at a time (so the proposed edit must be fully reviewed before they can make another edit proposal to another post).

Both of those (seemingly fairly small) changes would reduce the impact on a site's community of a user making small edits that are somehow out of place, and certainly don't appear unreasonable to me at first glance.

Yes, there are ways to trick the character <strike>bean</strike> counter. I'm arguing here that at some point, tricking it shouldn't be needed, *iff the edits are constructive.*

Yes, this means that reputation will carry meaning across sites, which may be a non-trivial change. So there's probably a decent chance that this won't get implemented. Still, it would be a very nice gesture toward people who spend a lot of time contributing on other sites, and just happen to come across somewhere they can make a small adjustment that improves a post.

Comment: Some sites are sensitive to "outside" users making a lot of edits. How would you propose addressing that concern?

Comment: @JonEricson There is already a mechanism for proposed edit ban on a per-site basis, and as I recall, one big trigger for that is if a user has proposed edits rejected in community review. If the edits are not constructive, they will *hopefully* be rejected in community review, which could (should) trigger that mechanism. Maybe users using this privilege could have a reduced threshold for when the proposed edit ban kicks in? Maybe they could have only a single outstanding edit at any one time, instead of the half-dozen-ish it is now for proposed edits? Both seem reasonable to me at a glance.

Answer (score 15):

#### Promote questions on per-site metas

It's understood that per-site metas don't have their own reputation, and therefore  bounties cannot work as elsewhere. But it's also true that important, difficult issues can get covered by a stream of burnination requests or duplicate support questions.

I propose that a user with very high reputation should be able to promote one meta question per month on the meta of their site.  In other words, they should be able to pick one question from the meta site and promote it. The promoted questions would be placed on the featured tab of the meta site, analogous to how bountied questions are promoted on the main site. (They should not automatically go into Community Bulletin, though -- that should be up to voters, as in present.) There would be no reputation spent, and no payouts.

Comment: Not going to the community bulletin may be good on big sites, but on most small sites, there is so little happening on meta, that having a *featured* tab would not make any difference. Rather, you are happy if people are visiting meta at all. In some cases, even the community bulletin does not suffice to attract people.

Answer (score 15):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Oct. 24, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*A while back I circulated an idea internally to let **everyone** see display name changes. The complication is that we don't know why people change their display names and sometimes they might have very good reasons to conceal their identity. Obviously it's still be possible to connect accounts to old accounts if you dig into comment replies and such. But it seems like a user has a reasonable expectation that old display names will remain private if they haven't posted anything with them.*

*Giving this information to moderators is not a problem since they are bound by the [moderator agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement). Making the information easily accessible is probably not a problem when it's possible to find the old display name on the site associated with the user. But figuring that out is complicated and error-prone. Our developers told me that it would be easier to block people from changing their display names instead of my scheme. So while I love the utility of this proposal, I don't think we can make it happen.*

---

## The ability to see all of a user's past display names/aliases.

Reference [this popular feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116801/148310) (and many others).

This is [already available for moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116794/148310) and [partially available from the API](https://stackapps.com/q/6276/7653) (needs to be in SEDE too).  Plus [Jeff did sort of promise it for everybody, long ago (and several redesigns ago)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101859/148310):

> We do have this information, and we can expose it. But the user page is quite busy already and needs a redesign, so I am not sure exactly when we will get to that.

Comment: Can you explain why this is a good idea?

Comment: Again if this feature is implemented, then why should it be restricted to high-rep users? The whole problem here is artificial limitation to start with, and your proposed solution just lowers that limitation to include yourself, instead of eliminating it altogether as it should be.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise, see the linked feature request (and the dozens of duplicate and linked posts from that).  There are many reasons but the main one for me is that many comment sequences make little sense due to name changes.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles I think chat-like highlights would be better. Past names seems like it shouldn't be put out there. The user probably changed it for a reason.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ high-rep regulars *can* and *do* already figure out who name-change users are on the non-massive (non-SO) sites, this would just save the hassle of hitting the user profile and scrolling until you see an answer you recognise. So I think this makes perfect sense as a high-rep-only mini-privilege, "we know you'll do this anyway so we made it easy"

Answer (score 14):

Close votes not to "time out" for double the normal time.   At least in tags the person has lots of rep in.

Close votes to be "promoted" in the close review queue, so they are more likely to be acted on.

Answer (score 14):

## Question Forgiveness

#### (or, Help a Question that was Downvoted Into Oblivion)

On occasion, there are questions that exist which may not have been well-worded when they were first asked, and attracted a ton of downvotes.

Someone may come along later and edit it into shape - be it the OP or some kind soul - but the question is still stuck at a myriad of downvotes.  In that state, regardless of whether or not it makes its way through the review queues, the question is still branded as being "bad" because it happened to catch a ton of negative hype when it first came up.

While this is a rare thing to see - a question downvoted so heavily but still has a chance - it would be a shame to lose questions that have suffered from either the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/1079354) or happened to catch users at a peak time who would disagree with it.

To that, I propose the Question Forgiveness micro-privilege.

Motivation:

Encourage community-driven investments on questions which are objectively *good* that may have fallen out of favor of the mob at a given time.

In a nutshell:

**You use your reputation to pay against the reputation of a heavily downvoted question.  The question then can rise above the filter thresholds and give it a chance to be seen/voted on once more.**

In finer detail:

- This is only usable against questions that have a score of **-10 or lower**.
- You would pay **50 + 2 reputation per point** to balance out the negative votes on the existing question, with a minimum of 50 reputation spent at a score of -10.  (Example:  A question scored -17 would cost you 64 reputation to revive, due to the 50 minimum and 14 extra rep, 2 for each point below 10.)  The question would not receive any upvotes, nor would the OP receive any reputation in the process.
- The question would be made more prominent for a period of time (72 hours).
- Voting on the question (negative voting) would not be visible to others; only the people that downvoted would be able to see their downvote  on the question.  **For users with the ability to see vote score**, they would either get the true upvote total, or the total comparing the forgiveness score with the original score.  They would also be able to see that this question is being forgiven, and that it should be revisited based on the merits of the question alone.
- At the end of the forgiveness period, the actual score is restored to the question.

The core of the suggestion is above, but here are two controversial additions to it:

- After the trial period, if the new question score balances out the negative score, then the 50+ reputation investment is refunded.  Otherwise, the reputation is lost.  (Example:  A question with -11 score has this applied to it; and there are 11 upvotes on the question.  Whomever offered it forgiveness would have their 52 reputation refunded.)
- After the trial period, if the new question score results in more downvotes than upvotes, then the investor would lose reputation (up to 10) proportional to the net total score.  (Example:  A question with -11 score has this applied to it, and there are 3 upvotes and 10 downvotes.  Since that's a net score of -7, the investor would lose 7 reputation.

Comment: I like what you're trying to accomplish.  I'm a little queasy about concealing votes without *saying* you're concealing votes, but as soon as you say it people will know why so I don't know how to do that cleanly.  (Election primaries also conceal negative votes, but they do it for all candidates; you're doing it for only some questions.)  I think you'll want the promotion period to be longer than 12-24 hours, but shorter than the week that a bounty gets -- maybe 2 or 3 days?  Remember: timezones, weekends, and the general press of life can keep people from noticing right away.

Comment: Those are some pretty good suggestions; the timing specifically would work well.   I'm not sure how to broach the "not telling people" portion since I feel that may defeat the purpose; I want the question to be revisited with a relatively clean slate and for it to be free of any previous prejudices.  If we're telling people that the actual vote is being hidden, I'm not so sure if the reaction we'd get - would it be positive, negative, or neutral?

Comment: Right -- if you tell people you're concealing the votes then people know it's a downvoted question, but if you don't you're being unpredictably dishonest (the reader no longer knows which questions report votes accurately and which don't).  I don't have a good answer to this.

Comment: Perhaps it could be added in with the view of close votes privilege.  If a question is in the process of being forgiven, then they could identify it and see either the accurate score, or the score before and during forgiveness.

Comment: I'd like to see something like this, but more like: pay 50 rep to hijack this question. Votes will be reset to 0 after your edit. **You are now this question's OP.** Only abandoned questions are viable. - "Abandoned" is a term to be decided: some amount of inactivity? There's a giant flow of Fallout 4 questions by 1 reps getting hammered pretty hard at Arqade. Users there seem apt to just try to box them out, with no attempt at constructive edits. The SOP seems to be: if OP is unresponsive, just throw the baby out with the bathwater. #wrongwaywrongroad

Comment: @Mazura:  There's very, very little value in taking over the OP's question; depending on the question, there's very little you could do to aid it as the OP once you do take it over.

Comment: [Bounties](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) achieve some of this intent by highlighting the question (special indicator + dedicated 'Featured' tab). If you start a bounty, your reason for doing so is also stated in the bounty's banner. However, you don't get the rep back when setting bounties; think of it as a donation.

Comment: @Lawrence:  A bounty isn't enough to undo the negative impression that a question gets if it's heavily downvoted.  Further, a bounty *never* awards the question, but rather the answer.

Comment: @Makoto What it does is give others a push and a stated reason to reconsider the question.

Comment: eh, keep it simple. you spend n rep per downvote cast to reset all of the voting back to 0. you can use said privilege once per month on open questions with more than n downvotes. no concealing, no voodoo, just a plain old reset button.

Comment: @KevinB:  Now that I'm revisiting this (I've simply engraved this URL into a shiny pitchfork that I use every now and then on MSO), I'm thinking of setting some minimum rep contribution. Not so sure on the monthly thing, but saying no more than three active ones (similar to bounties) would be alright, too.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but the implementation is too complicated. A simple reset would work better. The original down-voters get their 1 reputation back, and also get pinged that something happened to the question if they look at their reputation notices. Maybe a 20:1 reputation cost, a limited number of questions over some time period, and you can only set the question to -1 (so your up-vote takes it to zero)? That would be 180 reputation to reset a -10 question to zero score. I'm not sure that's high enough though.

Comment: @ColleenV:  Resetting this wouldn't be suitable since you're basically assuming that the person forgiving the question is absolutely correct in their decision.  By at least keeping that history around, you can determine if they actually *were* right by comparing new data to old data.

Comment: In my experience, this would only work on StackOverflow and maybe SuperUser.  On other sites, questions downvoted to -10 are hopeless: things like Holocaust denial on History, crackpottery on Physics, or "How do I hack Facebook?" on Information Security.  Questions that are merely poorly asked get one or two downvotes and an "unclear" closure.

Comment: I don't agree with the exact numbers. It shouldn't start at such a high amount and only increase by a very low amount per vote. Overall, though, this is a good feature request.

Answer (score 14):

## No ads and better privacy

It'd be great if we would show no ads or trackers (quantcast, etc.) for higher rep users. It would have no impact on revenue, basically, but it would show higher regard for them.

Answer (score 13):

## Ability to look at deleted comments (unless deleted by moderation).

Similar to the 10K privilege, even higher rep users could gain access to deleted comments.

Comment: Good idea, but please have them hidden by default with a [Show X deleted comments] button, not shown by default like deleted answers, else this will be a punishment not a reward!

Comment: I agree to that.

Answer (score 11):

## Edit the "Top Network Posts" List

This is an offshoot of another answer here: [show off the posts I'm most proud of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253687/300411).

Currently, a look at my Top Network Questions list makes it look like I spend all my time on ELU.SE:

[image: My top network posts]

But that's primarily a function of site traffic, not where I spend my time or what I am most proud of.

Thus, I propose allowing high-rep users to manually customize what appears under "Top Network Posts." This could mean either:

- Allow that a particular site's posts be hidden from in the list.

  - So I could hide all ELU posts.  Note that this is different from making ELU private: I don't mind if people know I am an ELU user, I just don't want its posts dominating my list.
- Allow manual selection of individual posts

  - Give me a list of posts to select from that meet some minimum vote threshold.  And override the behavior where the current site's posts are ignored in the calculation.

Comment: Dat [word-request] tag, though.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Exactly. The fact that I got lucky on a few word-request questions means that my (hopefully) more worthwhile contributions elsewhere don't appear.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244460/162102 (same problem, different request).

Comment: Since this would be tied to a privilege level it's inherently site-specific -- so edits to the list would affect just that site (though you could ask for a site-wide feature to do this).  I think that's probably a feature and not a bug; that way I can highlight posts *related to this site*, and have different lists on different sites.

Comment: Setting aside feasibility, etc... I like this idea, but I think it makes more sense as just a feature not as a site privilege. Top Network posts are a network-wide concern, so edits likely should apply network-wide (which makes locking access to it behind a single-site reputation kinda weird), if nothing else.

Answer (score 11):

## Ability to delete posts without score constraints

Right now it's impossible to delete a post which is upvoted unless you are a moderator. Unfortunately, a lot of poor posts get at least a score of one, and they need elected mod interventions to fix. The ability to clean up these posts would be very welcome.

Comment: Well, they _can_ be deleted from review if they get sent there by a LQP/NAA I think? But yes - it would be nice to have an option to VTD otherwise, even if it takes more users to do so, just like it works in review

Answer (score 11):

## Ability to lock and unlock posts

This can be limited (e.g. to 1 hour, no override of mods and CMs, etc.), but I don't see why users with enough rep should not be able to intervene and placate edit wars.

Comment: I like the part about no overrides of mods.

Answer (score 10):

## See vote counts on tag synonyms

I propose the ability to see vote counts on tag synonyms.

This is indeed a very minor privilege, but I do some tag moderation and I am sometimes curious how the balance between up and downvote on tag synonyms is so it would be nice to have.

Answer (score 9):

There are bounties to encourage good answers. Maybe it would be nice to have a similar super-charged way to reward really good **questions** by new/low rep users. I've noticed that the ratio of bad to good questions seems to be getting worse. So, users that have achieved a reasonably high level could get the ability to transfer a little of their rep to low rep users asking really good questions (i.e. well written, researched, etc), a little like a bounty for questions. Maybe 10 rep for really good question, and 25 for a superb question (or maybe even 25/50). This might encourage folks willing to spend time to compose good questions, even in areas that don't normally get lots of activity/upvotes.

Comment: Actually, the current bounty system sort of does this. If the question is really good, the additional attention should result in some upvotes. Moreover, if the question hasn’t been sufficiently answered well, the asker has an increased chance for this to happen, which is arguably a more important reward than some reputation. Still, bounties could be used more often in this way …

Answer (score 7):

## Ability to Accept Answers on Abandoned Questions

The sites are littered with questions that have an answer that clearly resolves the original question, but that has not *and probably never will be* **marked answered** because the asker has abandoned the question and/or his account.

**Not even moderators** can accept an answer for a question.  And the existence of these zombie "unaccepted" questions thwarts searches for questions that could use attention from a new expert.  (Believe me: I've tried to be helpful by going through questions with `hasaccepted:no` on a number of sites, but after seeing so many perfect-but-unaccepted answers I realized it's a waste of time.)

At some level of experience we can trust users to designate an "accepted answer."  To mitigate any concerns this feature could be implemented with the following limitations:

1. This only applies to questions with at least one upvoted answer but no accepted answer.
2. A user cannot accept his own answer to another user's question.
3. Only answers with positive net votes can be accepted.
4. The accept rep goes (if anywhere) to the original asker
5. Only questions by users who have not been seen in at least a month can have an answer accepted for them.

Finally, *if* the asker ever comes back and for any reason doesn't like the accepted answer he can change or unaccept it, as usual.

Comment: Has the "unanswered questions" view changed?  I thought "unanswered" meant "has no upvoted answers".

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Huh, it does seem to mean that now.  *Did* it change sometime in the last year?

Comment: I think it's been like that for a couple years, at least, but my memory on this is fuzzy.  If your "unanswered questions" view is overwhelming but there are good answers there, you have the ability to trim the list down a bit. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I must have been doing an advanced search.  Just amended my suggestion accordingly.

Comment: You [already proposed this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266443/privilege-for-tag-badges-accept-answers-to-abandoned-questions), it got downvoted (indicating unpopularity) and deleted. Why propose it again here?

Comment: @RobertLongson - it was proposed here first, and the deleted proposal would have been a duplicate but for my misunderstanding that I just clarified here.  Also, apparently I have too much rep ;)

Answer (score 7):

## Ability to add and remove post notices

This is actually super needed on Skeptics or any other site that uses them. It would *also* promote the usage of notices which we've found is usually a better strategy than commenting for repetitive comments (if it looks official, it becomes impersonal).

Answer (score 6):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Oct. 23, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*I think there's a good idea here, but it needs fleshing out. In particular, what can we put on this page that will be useful to high-reputation users that won't be useful for a brand new user? The most obvious thing is data on activities that require elevated privileges. We have something like that in the [10k tools page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools). (That page could use a makeover, by the way.) In addition, the added [site analytics for 25k users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) seems to cover some of the ideas below.*

---

#### What's New Dashboard

Give high rep users access to a page that shows recent posts in their favorite tags.  All questions from the past day, for example.  Each post should have relevant stats that help guide the user to whether they should try to provide a new answer (how many answers, what's the min/max/avg votes on the answers).  They can use these tools to min/max their further reputation gains.

Also throw in some other current trends for the site (I'm terrible with analytics, someone suggest some details) that just show current site activity, at a higher level than the review stats page.  Maybe show amount of activity (posts & comments) in popular tags for the day/week/month?  Or show some detailed analytics for the user's recent posts, like which posts have the most views and least views?  Tools that give them an idea of what's working and not working on the site in terms of traffic.

Comment: Is there any reason why any of this should not be available for everyone?

Comment: @corsair992 How does that argument not apply to the majority of the existing privileges?

Comment: The majority of the existing privileges are either moderation-related or have some potential for abuse (the "view vote counts" privilege is an exception to this, which I hate). None of your suggestions seem to present a similar argument for limiting their availability though.

Comment: @corsair992 Can you point to something in the question that indicates that our answers should have some good reason for only being available to high-rep users?

Comment: Actually, the main post also seems to be assuming that some useful features should be limited to high rep users, as shown by the example that they're considering. Needless to say, I [strongly disagree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253668/help-us-identify-micro-privileges-for-top-users#comment828514_253668) with that conclusion.

Comment: @corsair992 Well, I can say that I'm not a fan of you taking it out on me. Have fun down voting all these answers.

Comment: I am simply [expressing my disagreement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta).

Comment: @corsair992 This is an answer, not a question; you've misplaced where your votes should go.

Comment: I don't disagree with the main point of the question - only at the implication that the "micro-privileges" should not necessarily have a meaningful correlation with the reputation that they require. I do, however, disagree with your suggested feature as one of those privileges.

Comment: @Keen - Aren't you supposed to 'meta vote' on questions *and* answers here on Meta?

Answer (score 4):

#### Add a hovercard for accepted or highest scoring answer when looking for a question

The one thing that really annoys me when I'm searching for questions is that I can barely see any information about the accepted answer (or highest voted answers for questions without an accepted answer). There's an expanded [hovercard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7CuD.png) for users that contains some basic information about them. However, when you are looking at a question and you hover your cursor over it, it contains no info about the accepted answer:

[image]

I think there ought to be at least a *little* bit of information about the accepted/highest scoring answer when you hover over it, like it's score, answerer, and time it was answered.

Comment: Ooh, why Jon Skeet? Why not your hovercard?

Answer (score 2):

#### View the time votes were cast

Sometimes I come across posts that have been downvoted and edited. However, I have no way of knowing if it was downvoted mostly before or mostly after the edit. It would be convenient to be able to see when all the votes were cast so I can infer more accurately why they were cast. I think this would be good as a 1.5k privilege to fill in the gap between 1k and 2k.

Comment: You can already view the time a vote was cast, since it is recorded as a rep change.

Comment: @forest it's not very convenient to do it that way. There are questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-is-put-on-hold) that were asked years ago. It would take a very long time to go through the entire reputation history and see when all the votes were cast.

Comment: I think this is potentially interesting. However, I'd worry this might focus people on _who voted_. We already get the occasional detective comparing various timestamps to determine who downvoted (or occasionally upvoted) a post. This would encourage that useless behavior. What would you _do_ with the information once you got it?

Comment: @JonEricson determine *why* the post was downvoted. It's a lot easier to figure out the reason if you know how many votes were cast before and after an edit.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe the feature you want is voting by revision? So if the first revision has a negative and the second (or later) revision has no downvotes, we can infer the edit saved the post. Still tricky, I think, but I could see developing a concept of "influential edits" that change the course of post voting. (It would have to be statistically meaningful, I suppose, which would limit the number of edits it could be awarded to.) I think there's something here, but it would need some thought.

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Oct. 24, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*Questions get bumped when they are edited. There's no way to know if the edit is minor (removing an unneeded tag) or major (*[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) => [python](/questions/tagged/python)*). Sometimes you **want** to bump a question for community review. Breaking this rule is bound to be confusing with minimal gains.*

*By the way, limiting your retag efforts to one or two questions a day seems like a bad idea. Having been active on a tiny site (< 2 questions a day) I understand why it's awkward to flood the page with trivial edits. But it's far better to rip the bandaid off in one go than to dribble them out over days and weeks. Just do it and if anyone complains, ping me. I'm saving up a rant for that occasion. ;-)*

---

This is adapted from [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253116/255554):

### The first 10 tag-only edits per day to questions not on the front page do not bump the question on the front-page

The number 10 can be debated and one could add an additional criterion that the question must have a given age.

I sometimes come across a situation, where I want to retag a small bunch of older questions, e.g., to apply a new tag to appropriate old questions or to clean up an overused tag. Such a job would bump the respective questions to the front page, and thus on small pages, it’s usually considered best to only retag a one or two questions at a time and wait until they trickled down before editing the next ones. This is obviously quite annoying and makes me often refrain from such an undertaking altogether.

The rate limit is to avoid vandalism by rage-quitters or overzealous editors, who want to retag everything.

An alternative way to implement this would be to have such questions bumped with a probability of 10 % (or similar) and to always bump the first such question each day. This way, some of the respective questions would appear on the front page and thus be subject to control.

The questions may still be bumped in certain tag-specific views and similar to tag subscribers do not miss the questions.

Comment: I made the identical, unadapted suggestion and it ended up getting 4 downvotes and getting deleted.

Comment: No! Edits that change tags absolutely must bump the question. Otherwise people who subscribe or more generally are interested in one of the added tags, or who ignore one of the removed tags, will miss the question. Tag-changing edits bumping the question is not just about them getting peer review, it's first and foremost about reaching readers.

Comment: @Gilles: Good point, but this can mostly be addressed making the bumping specific to the respective view (provided that this is no nightmare to implement). The main concern here is the front page.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft How do you distinguish between people browsing the front page who are interested in the added tag (whether or not they are logged-in users who have marked this tag as interesting), and people browsing the front page who aren't interested in the added tag?

Comment: @Gilles: People browsing the front page would have seen the question when it was first posted already – unless they ignored a removed tag (hence, only *mostly be addressed).*

Comment: @Gilles, How about the question isn't bumped, but the people who "follow" the new tag (via the *subscribe* mechanism) get the standard notices.  And/or it's only bumped for subscribers.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles Doesn't work for people who use the tag as a filtering mechanism other than subscribing to it (ignoring, client-side filtering, mental filter).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this isn't going to be received well, but...

## Nothing.

In my mind, and maybe not everyone disagrees, a high reputation user should be someone who is knowledgeable and provides quality content.

These perks give too much incentive to 'game' the system and aggressively moderate, which I don't think is healthy, and is already happening fairly frequently.

If you look at where these users' reputation comes from (my own included), you'll see that it's primarily from answering and asking basic, bordering on stupid, questions that are asked frequently by students and new developers. Some users take this a step further by optimizing the question for search indexing, and then aggressively closing duplicates and referring users to their own content; *which is likely also a duplicate of an older question, itself*.

These perks just incentivize people to sit around all day and play Stack Exchange like a game. While there's no value to having five duplicates of '*What does << mean in Java?*' asked and answered each day, I think it's also detrimental for users to receive perks (specifically, privileges) for aggressively moderating these questions.

Comment: "These perks just incentivize people to sit around all day and play StackExchange like a game." ... gamification, anyone?

Answer (score -2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Oct. 24, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*Votes are like opinions: [everybody has one](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/thats-just-like-your-opinion-man). Voting isn't always scientific, but it's pretty much the best option we have to divide helpful content from unhelpful. Weighting the opinions of high reputation users (who can throw some weight around in comments and chat in any case) seems counterproductive. There's also the complication of building a UI for a very small fraction of users.*

### Supervotes.

At some very high rep level -- say 50k -- the user might get 3 daily "supervotes". A supervote is in all respects just like multiple regular up or down votes: let's say a supervote is worth 3 up or down votes. These would be incredibly handy in righting wrongs: degrading an accepted but wrong answer, or rewarding a great answer that's gotten buried in the noise. I see these situations on a regular basis; it would be great to have a little extra muscle to help fix them.

Comment: This. We've all seen the "I wish I could upvote twice" comments on super posts. Super votes are the appropriate measure.

Comment: −2. `:-)` The net vote (as well as its two components) is a good measure of *how much of* the community has voted on the post, and this would remove that.

Comment: This smells a bit too much to me like ["Some animals are more equal than others"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Animal_Farm#Chapter_10)

Comment: @jakebeal I'm going to come out and say that's exactly what it is. Is SO a democracy, or a meritocracy? I'm going to go with the latter.

Comment: High rep users already can afford to offer bounties to answers that they like, rewarding those users (although it doesn't affect answer order).

Comment: I am totally loving the votes on *all* of these microprivileges.  This one has +12 and -9 as of this writing, and many others are similar. Wonder how super votes would change that balance? :)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill While SO certainly strives to be a meritocracy, rep alone is _not_ an adequate measure of merit. It is a measure of activity. Now, if downvotes were -10 to match out an upvote's +10, then rep would more accurately represent a person's standing in the community.

Answer (score -4):

### Ability to Favorite a User

Ok, I know this have been a feature request a while ago and have been shot down, due to it converting the SE sites into a social network. But I don't think this will hurt if it's available for just the 10K users.
The purpose could be to read more of their posts in future or probably even to track the user's suspicious behaviour. I have never seen the mod tools for 10k+ users, so I have no idea if it's already available or not. But it'd be a nice addition, if it isn't already available.

Answer (score -7):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Oct. 24, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*Besides other problems, the chat super ping has an awkward interface that makes it a hassle. Sorry to burst your bubble. ;-)*

---

## The ability to "superping" any user

I'm not a mod, but I understand this is a power that exists... Maybe it will be helpful to address users directly, without hassle.

Comment: You mean the ability to ping any user in chat?

Comment: @ArthurFischer The way I read it, he's talking about comments. Where you can now @ ping posters, previous commenters, etc, you could ping everybody instead. I can't really think of a lot of cases where I would find his useful. But if others want it, it might be a nice perk.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I have a feeling something like that was intended, but currently even mods can't simply `@ping` any user in comments. The only mod power I can think of along these lines is the [chat superping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/super-ping/info).

Comment: That's not really a micro privilege though, it's an actual power.

Answer (score -8):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) *Oct. 23, 2015* (Jon Ericson)

*I addressed this in a comment. Flag queues can be a problem, but the solution isn't to shame moderators. (I don't think that's the intention of the idea, but it's how things would play out practically.) Rather we need to work on ways to help them handle the load.*

---

Let them see a ~ 15 minute cached count of the number of moderator attention flags. Just the count, not the actual posts that were flagged. This will help them get an idea of how many flags moderators are handling, how many of them happen on their site, and also to let them decide if they want to give some verbal support to the moderators to cleanse the mod queue.

Comment: I don't really think the moderators need any "verbal support". I get that you aren't actually talking about people complaining, but that's likely what will happen. :-(

Comment: I'd prefer a "tip your moderator" feature on flags. Tips should be in the form of poetry or bratwurst.

Comment: Depending on the quality, either poetry or bratwurst could be considered + or - ...

Answer (score -8):

A minority opinion, but someone has to say it:

Y'know, some of us are supremely uninterested in this points thing. For us, using score to gate potentially dangerous permissions makes some sense but the win-a-new-knob idea really is not a motivator, and putting anything actually useful behind such a wall comes across more as self-defeating, discouraging folks from participating by making them jump through unnecessarily high hoops.

This, along with the endless demands that I reclassify comments as answers and vice versa, will probably cause me to abandon SE at some point. It has become too caught up in playing points games and splitting hairs, and is losing sight of its stated goals.

Comment: So, what is the micro-privilege that you are proposing?

Comment: I'm asking whether new micros will actually be worth the investment, or if this is just inertia carrying things forward long past the point of diminishing returns. There are places where all of SE would benefit from some invested resource. Unless this is specifically a reward for the _developers_, I would prioritize it lower than those. But I accept that even by the standards of this mob I'm a wierdo.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an... oh I see what ya did there. Plus one because I agree. Give people all the stupid hats they want; just let the site work how it's supposed to... for everyone.

Answer (score -11):

I'm still ambivalent about microprivileges, but I'll suggest::

***Who agreed?***

Would show a list of the up-voters on our own question, answer, or comment.

(I do not recommend "who disagreed" -- that way lie personal arguments -- but it'd be interesting to see whether my endorsements came from folks I particularly respect, which could be a bit of egoboo, especially if I wasn't sure. "Me too" without "me too"s.)

Failing that, a rough histogram of rep of endorsers would give some of the same info without any individuals being named.

Comment: Voting is anonymous. Period. It doesn't matter if it is up or down.

Comment: Understood. Thought this was limited enough to be a possible exception; if not, not. As the floating-head meditation guide in the ad said, "I'm unattached."