# Personalized feed, questions likely to be answerable

Tags: discussion, feed

Tags are very useful, but it would be even better if you could get all questions you are likely to be able to answer in one place. An algorithm would look at your answer history and see what tags or combination of tags you have answered to most. The feed would then contain unanswered questions relevant to you. Sorted either by newest or "most relevant".
In this way, the "pro" users can answer even faster which makes everyone happy.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253683/162102

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289702, also results of first version of test: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286915. In short, not an easy problem, but also something that is being actively researched. A successful algorithm, once found, can presumably be used to generate a feed-style interface as well.