# Chat-like highlights to link old comment strings

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

I noticed that displaying previous names was a desirable feature to many people. However, one of the main reasons appears to be so that you can see comment replies easier. I think that this would be almost as confusing, and rather impractical to implement.

Instead, when you hover over a message a chat-like highlight could be displayed for all linked comments. Displaying previous names would have to be done on the profile page most likely, and I think that practically nobody would care to go to someone's profile, find their previous names, go back, and see who replied to who.

---

**Based on this answer:** https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254769/275761