# Filter for "questions I can answer that no one else has"

Tags: discussion, support, search, unanswered-questions

Like everyone, I want a list of stackexchange questions that I can answer that no one else has already answered. More specifically:

- The question must be at least 1 hour old. I'm not looking to race someone else to answer. As nearly as I can tell, there is no filter for question age, but I might be missing something.
- The question must have no *upvoted* answers. Some people never approve an answer, but an upvote tells me the question has been sufficiently answered. There is a filter for "n answers" (including n=0), but not sure about upvoted answers.
- The question must have no upvoted comments. Some people put answers in comments, so an upvoted comment tells me that someone is at least making progress on the question.
- The question itself must not have a negative score.

Is it possible to create such a filter?

The general concept I'm going for is:

- There are people who know more than me in virtually every subject.
- However, these people aren't necessarily always answering questions.
- There are some subjects where I know more than most (not all) people.
- In these subjects, I want to find questions that people have asked, and that other people have viewed, but not been able to answer. Presumably, the super-expert on the subject could easily answer the question, but perhaps I can answer it quicker.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the presence of an upvoted comment a stronger indicator of answered-ness than the presence of a yet-to-be-upvoted answer.

Comment: Did you try [constructing such a search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)? How far did you get and where are you stuck? score:1.. will return answers with a positive score for instance which is one of your bullet points. You can't search for comments though so that part is not possible.

Comment: On-site search doesn't give you a way to search for questions whose *answers* have certain properties.  You can do this with SEDE if you're willing to wait a week.  I [proposed something similar to this as a micro-privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253683/162102), but I'd be happy to see it for everybody.

Answer (score 3):

- You can't search based on comments.
- There is no search parameter based on hours since post creation; although I think there should be.

To filter based on the score of question and answers, use the  parameters

```
isanswered:0 hasaccepted:0 score:0..
```

(possibly adding your tags, `intags:mine`), sort by newest and then determine which page of results roughly corresponds to "one hour ago" (not the first one since it has the newest questions). The page number will depend on the activity of the site and your tag filter. Navigate to that page and bookmark it.

Comment: "score:0.." will return *questions* with non-negative score, but I haven't found a way to search for questions with *answers* of a certain score.  Do you know of one?

Comment: Only what's in the answer: is:question isanswered:0 searches questions where no answer has positive score. For other score ranges, one needs SEDE.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I've done that kind of search in SEDE but that turns it into "search older questions that I can answer", which isn't always what I'm looking for.