# Visualising statistics of Stack Exchange site over time

Tags: discussion, statistics

Is it possible to visualise the statistics of a Stack Exchange Network site over time, to see whether it's gaining momentum or slowing down?

I'm interested in particular in the Japanese version of Stack Overflow, which doesn't have an Area51 profile.

Comment: You can easily generate interesting site statistics using [data.se]. Be creative.

Comment: Example, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251842/456814

Comment: Another example, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252757/456814

Answer (score 3):

Access to Site Analytics for a site is restricted to Moderators of that site and those with the [Access to Site Analytics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) privilege on that site:

Non-moderator access has been opened up only [relatively recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253669/215590).

Comment: Thanks for this info. I think it's wrong that only high-rep users have access to that info, as a site's health should be the concern of all the community.

Comment: [It's a 5k privilege on Beta sites @Andrew](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), you should already have it for Japanese.SE.

Comment: @ben I'm referring to ja.stackoverflow.com, not japanese.SE.